# Making a deck "server side" in node.js/socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io

So I'm sure this is fairly basic and I'm over-complicating it. I'm making an online web card game using express, node.js, nodemon, socket.io and phaser3. Basically all players need to draw from the same deck. What I am trying to do is have one deck on the server side that is an array that has the value popped and sent to the player. This way no two players have the same card. If each player has their own deck, then eachtime a player draws a card, every other player has to remove that card from their version of the deck. I tried simply importing the Deck.js file I wrote into my server.js(run with node.js, express, and nodemon), but I then get an error that says "cannot use import statement outside a module."

this is my server.js

```
const server = require('express')();
const http = require('http').createServer(server);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
import Deck from './client/src/helpers/deck'
let players = [];


io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log('A user connected: ' + socket.id);
    players.push(socket.id);
    io.emit('addPlayer', socket.id); 
    socket.on('dealCards', function () {
        io.emit('dealCards');
    });
    socket.on('cardPlayed', function(gameObject, player){
        io.emit('cardPlayed', gameObject, player);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        console.log('A user disconnected: ' + socket.id);
        players = players.filter(player => player !== socket.id);
    });


});

http.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log('Server Started!');
});
```

This is my Deck.js, at the top there are two arrays with all of the prompts/ answers.

```
export default class Deck { 
    constructor(scene, isPrompt) {
        let cards = [];
        if(isPrompt) {
            cards = prompts;
        }
        else {
            cards = answers;
        }
        this.draw = () => {
            return cards.pop();
        }

        this.shuffle = () => {
            for (let i = cards.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
                let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
                [cards[i], cards[j]] = [cards[j], cards[i]]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate any help!!

Comment: Try changing `export` to `module.exports = ` then instead of using `import` just require the module and use it as you would've used it if it was imported

Comment: That worked great! Thank you so much!

Comment: No problem, it's not worth posting an answer so I'll leave it in the comments